# infinite scss class loop

Tags: css, sass

i have this code for 5 item classes

```
  @for $num from 1 through 5 {
    .item-#{$num} {
      transform-origin: top center;
      animation: rotateX 300ms ($num * 60ms) ease-in-out forwards;
    }
    .item-#{$num} + .item-last {
      transform-origin: top center;
      animation: rotateX 300ms (($num + 1) * 60ms) ease-in-out forwards;
    }
  }
```

but when i create 6 or more items it doent work..

how can i make it infinite? or may be some different way.

thx who answer it.

Comment: just change value after through 5 to through (number of times you want the loop to run)

Comment: i wanna loop run infinitly((

Comment: No you don't. Your sass will never stop rendering if you make an infinite loop. If did did ever stop the filesize of your css output would be enormous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use JS for a use case like this. It will work with however many divs you have (infinite like you want) but it will not bloat your stylesheet to infinite file size.  I had to guess a little bit about your HTML structure.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[class^='item-']").forEach((item, index) => {
   item.style.animation = `rotateX 300ms ${index * 60}ms ease-in-out forwards`;
   const nextSibling = item.nextElementSibling;
   if(nextSibling){
     nextSibling.style.animation = `rotateX 300ms ${(index + 1) * 60}ms ease-in-out forwards`;
   }
})
```

```css
[class^=item-] {
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      background: blue;
      transform-origin: top center;
}

.last-item {
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      background: pink;
      transform-origin: top center;
}

@keyframes rotateX {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 
 100% {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
 }

}
```

```html
<div class="item-1"></div>
<div class="last-item"></div>
<div class="item-2"></div>
<div class="last-item"></div>
<div class="item-3"></div>
<div class="last-item"></div>
<div class="item-4"></div>
<div class="last-item"></div>
<div class="item-5"></div>
<div class="last-item"></div>
```

Comment: thx, i didnt think about it. thx very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to implement a class loop:

```
  @for $num from 1 through 999999 {
    .item-#{$num} {
      transform-origin: top center;
      animation: rotateX 300ms ($num * 60ms) ease-in-out forwards;
    }
    .item-#{$num} + .item-last {
      transform-origin: top center;
      animation: rotateX 300ms (($num + 1) * 60ms) ease-in-out forwards;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ok if you want gigabytes of css generated.

Comment: maybe better solution?